# Flory Theory of the real Polymer: Why is the Gain per Monomer contribution proportional to $kT$?

Tags: statistical-mechanics, polymers

In Flory Theory of the real Monomer (see for example Rubinstein / Colby Polymer Physics, p.102), we want to estimate the free enrgy of a real polymer, that doesn't admit overlaps in the monomers. To do so, what I see in multiple sources (for example here: [Script](https://www.eng.yale.edu/polymers/docs/classes/polyphys/lecture_notes/4/handout4.pdf)) is that we assume the distribution of an ideal gas for the monomers, give a probability for two Monomers to be in the same position (this is proportional to $N^2 / R^3$) and then state that to prevent such overlaps from happening, we must use the energy $k_B T$. Now I want to know, how this energy comes into place.

Why do we need the energy $k_B T$ to change the microstate with two overlapping Monomers to a microstate without an overlapping microstate?